Recommendations for Transparent Materials to Build a Chloroform Vapor Box for PLA Smoothing?
I’m planning to build a small, enclosed box for smoothing PLA prints using chloroform vapor. I want to use a transparent material, similar to plexiglass, so I can monitor the process without opening the box.

What materials would work best for this? I’m looking for something that’s resistant to chloroform but easy to work with.

Has anyone built something similar or have experience with chloroform-safe materials?

Are there any potential issues I should be aware of, like warping or chemical reactions with the material?


I appreciate any advice or insights! Thanks in advance.

for small prints, a large glass/cup/mug or a cheap glass "vase" could have enough room. A glass/ceramic mixing bowl and an old window can be used for larger prints.

When you want transparent and chemically inert, glass is always the first choice.  You should find clear silicone adhesive/sealant will allow you to join the glass plates and be reasonably impervious to chloroform.  In fact, you may be able to repurpose a small aquarium...
